# How to create SQL multiple count count query by date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that selects counts group by department.

```
select department, count(*) group by department
```

This returns two columns data result. I wonder if select cout, count by today and count by this month same query.

```
Department  Total  Today  ThisMonth
AAA         40     8      23
BBB         20     6      11
```

Comment: Add more details to the question. Like the sample dataset and the SQL you have used.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: postgresql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
select department,count(*),
sum(case when datecolumn= GETDATE() then 1 else 0 end) as Today,
sum(case when month(datecolumn) =month(GETDATE() and year(datecolumn) =year(GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) as ThisMonth
from YourTable
group by department
```

Comment: but month may be year fo 2016 or 2017 or else

Comment: Check the Updated Code

Answer (score 0):

@SimarjeetSingh has already answered this.

except the comparison with datecolumn should happen with datepart only, GETDATE() retuns time with it.

```
select department, count(*) as Total,
sum(case when cast(datecolumn as date)= cast(GETDATE() as date)  then 1 else 0 end) as Today,
sum(case when month(datecolumn) =month(GETDATE()) and year(datecolumn) = year(GETDATE()) then 1 else 0 end) as ThisMonth
from YourTable
group by department
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison of datecoulmn with getdate() should be by MMYYYY to get ThisMonth total.

```
select department,count(*) as Total,
sum(case when convert(varchar,datecolumn,106)= convert(varchar,GETDATE(),106) then 1 else 0 end) as Today,
sum(case when cast(month(datecolumn) as varchar) + cast(year(datecolumn) as varchar)  = cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar) + cast(year(GETDATE()) as varchar)  then 1 else 0 end) as ThisMonth
from YourTable
group by department
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  department,
  count(*) as total,
  count(*) filter (where datecolumn = current_date) as count_for_today,
  count(*) filter (where date_trunc('month', datecolumn) = date_trunc('month', current_date)) as count_for_month
from
  your_table
group by
  department
```

[`FILTER` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)
[`date_trunc` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)